# Laravel EventListener doesn't fire

Tags: php, laravel

I created an event and listener in Laravel, but the listener doesn't fire. It does actually fire on my colleague's machine. That makes me think that the actual code works and that the configuration is in order.

Listener:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners\Consensus;

use App\Events\Consensus\ManualGroupChannelNotificationEvent;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

/**
 * Class ManualGroupChannelNotificationListener
 * @package App\Listeners\Consensus
 */
class ManualGroupChannelNotificationListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  ManualGroupChannelNotificationEvent  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(ManualGroupChannelNotificationEvent $event)
    {
        Log::debug('Listener');
    }
}
```

Event:

```
<?php
namespace App\Events\Consensus;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

/**
 * Class ManualGroupChannelNotificationEvent
 * @package App\Events\Consensus
 */
class ManualGroupChannelNotificationEvent
{
    use Dispatchable;

    /*
     * ExternalComment constructor.
     *
     * @param Comment $comment
     * @param User $currentUser
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        Log::debug('Event');
    }
}
```

EventServiceProvider:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\Consensus\ManualGroupChannelNotificationEvent' => [
        'App\Listeners\Consensus\ManualGroupChannelNotificationListener',
    ],
];
```

Firing the event:

```
event(new ManualGroupChannelNotificationEvent());
```

I ran all commands to clear cache etc., but still it doesn't work.

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan queue:restart
```

If this code works on another machine, what else can I do to make it work on mine?

Other info:

- My logging does work; the Event-message is logged.
- Other, similar events do work.

Comment: Is your setup configured to handle `debug` level events? That's controlled by a setting in `.env` and `config/app.php`, via `'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),`; Yours might be something different.

Comment: I do get the Event-message in my log, just not the Listener-message.

Comment: Double check again your namespaces, also check /storage/log/laravel.log if it contains something

Comment: Nothing in the logs (except for "Event") and namespaces are correct. It works on my colleague's computer without any changes. Other events do work on mine.

Comment: Try to run the code in some isolated env, like a docker image - this will help you to find the wrong configuration. Or stay using docker for your app :)

Comment: Hope this article will help you

https://vegibit.com/8-steps-to-success-with-laravel-events/

Comment: What version of Laravel do you use?

Comment: @UdoE. version 6.1.0

Comment: Can Laravel resolve your Listener properly? Check in tinker with `class_exists('App\Listeners\Consensus\ManualGroupChannelNotificationListener')` or `app()->make('App\Listeners\Consensus\ManualGroupChannelNotificationListener')`, the latter of which is how Laravel actually resolves the Listener from within the Dispatcher. If that's false or errors-out, check that the filename matches the class name _exactly_. I've seen issues in the past where things worked on a case-insensitive filesystem but failed on a case-sensitive filesystem because the class file had the wrong capitalization.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I deleted the repo and cloned again, it works now.

Comment: Accepting your own answer does not award the bounty to you or refund the reputation amount in any circumstances. Make sure you award bounty to someone else who gave a great answer.

Comment: You are accepting your own answer !! You should update the question itself to help others

Answer (score 1):

First thing, try to apply `chmod -R 777 storage/logs` it might be just an authorisation issue.

Maybe the registering of your events failed, you can try to add this to your EventServiceProvider

```php
/**
 * Determine if events and listeners should be automatically discovered.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function shouldDiscoverEvents()
{
    return true;
}
```

Is your second working machine the same as the first one ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do get the log message from the Event, just not from the Listener, so logging works. Adding that method doesn't make a difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I tested your setup in Laravel 5.8 by manually creating your classes and both the event and listener are logged correctly.

I will suggest you avoid manually creating your event and listener classes. Instead, first specify them in `EventServiceProvider.php` as you have done:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\Consensus\ManualGroupChannelNotificationEvent' => [
        'App\Listeners\Consensus\ManualGroupChannelNotificationListener',
    ],
];
```

Then generate the necessary class files automatically using this artisan command

```
php artisan event:generate
```

You can now modify the generated classes by including the `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;` directive line and then use the `Log::debug()` method call in your event constructor and listener handler methods.

Try this suggested method and see if it works. I don't think it is a case of storage access permission since the event logs successfully in your case.